# When websocket server stops/restarts, will the WebSocket object on the client side be set to null?

Tags: javascript, websocket

When a websocket server restarts/stops, will the WebSocket object on the client side set to null, or the readyState property of the WebSocket object just set to 3?

Comment: You should not add all the websocket tags to your question. Please provide some codes you have written so far. It's unclear which library you are using. (Also, simple check `if(websocket==null)` ...)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should just check if the WebSocket object is `null`, and if it isn't then your code should check if the `readyState` is 3.

Comment: I was not checking for null. Now I have got a sentry log saying "Cannot read property 'readyState' of null". So, I want to be sure if that log came due to server restart/stop.

Comment: You will have to check your code to see what is setting the variable to `null` and why. A WebSocket cannot set your reference to it to `null`.